# How to Test the .xap files in unlocked windows phone?

Tags: windows-phone-7

i installed the zune software and windows developer tools .while testing the .xap file in LG c-900 real device i got the

"Application launch failed. Ensure that the device screen is unlocked and device is developer unlocked. For details on developer unlock, visit http://go.microsoft.com/fwlink/?LinkId=195284"

Please tell me how to test the .xap file in LG c-900 unlocked phones?

Answer (score 5):

You can use Visual Studio or Application Deployment tool to install .xap on your device.
In order to install it successfully, you have to check those requirements :

1. You have to unlock your phone : if you have a developer account, you can unlock it with the Windows Phone Developer Registration tool installed with the developer tools.
2. Launch Zune software.
3. Unlock your phone screen.

Are those steps done ?

Answer (score 2):

If your phone is unlocked then in VS you need to set that you want to debug your application on a Windows Phone Device and not the Emulator.

[Debugging on the Phone Series](http://wildermuth.com/2010/7/29/Developing_for_the_Windows_Phone_7_-_Part_2_Debugging_on_the_Phone)

Answer (score 1):

You need to get the App Hub account to unlock your phone. Otherwise you will have to test your app on the simulator.

Personal suggestion: if you really just need to have a try on the physical phone, ask someone who has the account to share it with you, it does no harm to both him and Microsoft.